# customtkinter radiobutton function

Tags: python, callback, radio-button, customtkinter

I am making a custom tkinter GUI and want to use some radiobuttons.
The problem is that I don't exactly know how to do that: I have this piece of code:

This is the "callback"function

```
def print_var(*_):
    ldakf= value.get()
    print(ldakf)
```

Here the buttons are created:

```
def createe_rad_but():
    radiobutton_var = tkinter.IntVar(value=1)
    radiobutton_1 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=root, variable=radiobutton_var, value=1)
    radiobutton_1.place(relx=0, x=80, y=50 + allast*45, anchor=NW)

    radiobutton_2 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=root, variable=radiobutton_var, value=2)
    radiobutton_2.place(relx=0.35, x=80, y=50 + allast*45, anchor=NW)

    radiobutton_3 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=root, variable=radiobutton_var, value=3)
    radiobutton_3.place(relx=0.7, x=80, y=50 + allast*45, anchor=NW)
    radiobutton_var.trace('w', print_var)
```

[The app with radiobuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUi4n.png)

I want them to have other texts instead of CTkButton and the "callback function" must print the selected radiobutton and make them all state="disabled"